# Google Spreadsheets QUERY() to combine multiple sheets, by value of one field

Tags: google-sheets

I am having the following problem: There are two Sheets in my document which contain different data about the cities (which are listed in column A in both cases). I am trying to create a combination where the data about a given city is merged from the second sheet.

I was trying to explore QUERY function, as it's suggested in a similar topic:
`=QUERY({Sheet1!A2:C5;Sheet2!A2:C5},"select Col1 where Col1 <>''")` However it's not clear how to replace the `where Col1 <>''` with an appropriate statement.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Since [Query Docs](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/querylanguage) does not support Join similar to SQL, one workaround is to use `ARRAYFORMULA`, `VLOOKUP`, and indirect reference to achieve a similar result:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA({Sheet1!A1:C5,VLOOKUP(Sheet1!A1:A5,Sheet2!A1:B5,COLUMN(INDIRECT("R1C2:R1C"&COLUMNS(Sheet2!A1:B5),0)),0)})
```

From your tables on the question, the result looks like this:

[image: Results]

References:

[ARRAYFORMULA()](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093275)

[VLOOKUP()](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093318)

[INDIRECT()](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093377)

[COLUMN()](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093373)

[COLUMNS()](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093374)